# Need to fix a sub-query and can't figure what went wrong

Tags: mysql, sql

I used a sub-query that returns all orders placed on the last day of activity that can be found in the Orders table.

Here is what I came up with:

```
SELECT orderid, orderdate, customerid, employeeid
FROM Orders
WHERE orderdate = MAX(orderdate);
```

This is what I received:
Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please don't add the MySQL tag to your SQL Server (T-SQL or just SQL) queries. They don't operate the same way, so you need to be very specific. Or you'll actually get what you're asking for and then it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error roughly translates to: You cannot use `MAX()` unless you use `GROUP BY` or the like.

So here's a quick way to rewrite your query:

```
SELECT orderid, orderdate, customerid, employeeid
FROM Orders
WHERE orderdate = (SELECT TOP 1 orderdate FROM Orders ORDER BY orderdate DESC);
```

But your orderdate could potentially be timestamped, so I would add this as well:

```
SELECT orderid, orderdate, customerid, employeeid
FROM Orders
WHERE orderdate = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, (SELECT TOP 1 orderdate FROM Orders ORDER BY orderdate DESC)));
```

I realize this isn't MySQL, but I hope you or someone else is able to rewrite this solution to MySQL for you.

Answer (score 1):

@Trafz's answer was close, but it won't work in MySQL specifically (LIMIT 1 not TOP 1). Likewise, depending on the size of your table, which storage engine you're using, and what indexes you have, you might actually be better off with a join, eg,

```
SELECT orderid, a.orderdate, customerid, employeeid
FROM Orders AS a
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(orderdate) as orderdate FROM Orders) AS b
ON a.orderdate = b.orderdate
;
```

The later should work on all major SQL implementations (there is some difference between syntax regarding TOP / LIMIT) and it might get you further along with the SQL optimizer... but even if not, it won't be any worse.

Comment: I realized that as well, but I had a hunch that OP simply added the MySQL tag to give his issue greater exposure. His question from yesterday says he's using `Northwind Database SQL 2012`. So I replied anyway.

Comment: Hey man, it's all good. I figured you probably just didn't recall the MySQL syntax right off the top of your head. Every time I move from MySQL to Postgres or SQL Server, I end up forgetting some bit of nuance somewhere. If you can keep that straight most of the time, let me know how you do it! But vis a vis your answer, seriously, it was  basically right (I upvoted it cause I mean, really, who can keep up with all the variation all the time). But I did want to go ahead and correct the syntax, and also suggest a way to avoid anything breaking if tomorrow he uses some other DB :-)